# What's the point of the "steps" tag?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

[steps](/questions/tagged/steps) has [only 5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/steps?sort=votes), all by low-rep users.  There's no wiki for it, and there isn't any coherent link between the questions.  It seems to me that it's a prime target for burnination.

Comment: I cleared a set of them by hand, to see if there were any better tags for each of the questions. I cleared 10 or so, enough for me for now.

Comment: burn the tag!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were only 4 questions with this tag, so why didn't you just edit it out yourself?

Anyway, I did so.

Answer (score 1):

[Cucumber: Shared steps, where to place them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960765/cucumber-shared-steps-where-to-place-them)

Seems like a legit use, given steps has a certain meaning here that I have no idea of.

---

However, questions like

[SQL select step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632260/sql-select-step)

have no legit use for the tag.

Comment: They're not called "shared steps" in Cucumber (as I see you've added a tag for them). They're quite simply called "steps". Maybe call it [cucumber-steps]? Not sure how useful it would be still. [cucumber] seems adequate.

Comment: I reverted that. It was my first venture into editing, and I regretted doing so on shaky grounds. Thanks for the help though, @BoltClock'saUnicorn